# VSPackage command that creates a new solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vspackage

How can I create a command in a VSPackage that creates a new solution with a new project (C# Class Library) in it, containing 1 .cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very straighforward but there is an interesting guide on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx) that explains how to do it. It is for an Add-in but in a VSPackage you have the same set of Visual Studio DTE objects available (the DTE application).

You can define a method that uses GetProjectTemplate and AddFromTemplate to create two console projects. You can define in the method `Initialize` of your VSPackage class a OLE menu command (if that is what you are looking for):

```
 protected override void Initialize()
 {
     //// Create the command for the menu item.
     var aCommand = new CommandID(GuidList.GuidCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIdList.CmdId);
     var menuItemEnable = new OleMenuCommand((s, e) => createProjectsFromTemplates(), aCommand);
 }
```

And then define a method associated to the command (`createProjectsFromTemplates` in this case) that creates a solution with a project:

```
    private DTE2 _mApplicationObject;

    public DTE2 ApplicationObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mApplicationObject != null) return _mApplicationObject;
            // Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE
            var dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
            _mApplicationObject = dte as DTE2;
            return _mApplicationObject;
        }
    }

public void createProjectsFromTemplates()
{
    try
    {
        // Create a solution with two projects in it, based on project 
        // templates.
        Solution2 soln = (Solution2)ApplicationObject.Solution;
        string csTemplatePath;

        string csPrjPath = "C:\\UserFiles\\user1\\addins\\MyCSProject"; 
        // Get the project template path for a C# console project.
        // Console Application is the template name that appears in 
        // the right pane. "CSharp" is the Language(vstemplate) as seen 
        // in the registry.
        csTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate(@"Windows\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.vstemplate", 
          "CSharp");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("C# template path: " + 
          csTemplatePath);
            // Create a new C# console project using the template obtained 
        // above.
        soln.AddFromTemplate(csTemplatePath, csPrjPath, "New CSharp 
          Console Project", false);

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

For Visual Studio versions after 10.0 the zip for template projects is not available anymore. The .vstemplate must be referenced and it is possible to find all the project templates under the folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1x.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\
```

More info on this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y3kkate1(v=vs.110).aspx).

The method should create a solution with one C# project based on the c# project template (e.g. containing class1.cs as initial file).

You can define your own template as well if you wish and create a solution based on that custom template. Here is a guide from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx) on how to create custom templates.

hope it helps.

Comment: Very insightful, thank you. But how do you know to write "ConsoleApplication.zip" for the template? Where do you see this? In what right pane?